# What does "this comment is not valid for voting or flagging" mean?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, comment-voting

I'm trying to upvote a comment and I get a dialog box with

> this comment is not valid for voting
>   or flagging

What's that about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two reasons:

- Between the time that you started reading the comment to when you flagged or hit the upvote, it has been deleted.
- The post you're looking at, to which the comment belongs, is locked.

Comment: That's a pretty unclear message, isn't it. Maybe "This comment has been deleted" would be better.

Comment: Yep - that appears to be exactly the case

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once; the comment was on the question and the question was <strike>closed</strike> locked. I assumed that was the reason. Other comments on the same question were also not upvote-able.

However, comments on answers to that question were upvote-able, so I don't know what's the idea here.

Comment: Closed you can still vote on. Locked, not so much.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize there was a difference between closed and locked (what is it, btw? no one can vote to re-open a locked question?)

Comment: @hasen IIRC, "locked" might be better termed "frozen" - no votes, no comments, no edits. I think it's generally used when an all-out edit war has been taking place. "Closed" more means "no more answers". ...Of course, I might be wrong.